# CorelDRAW Print Merge automation with VBA

Tags: vba, coreldraw

Is there a way to automate the Print Merge function of CorelDRAW X6 using VBA?

The way I would normally try to figure this out would be to record a macro, and then do a print merge. However in this case the macro is blank - leading me to believe CorelDRAW does not allow VBA control of this feature.

I have found nothing online about this - but have found some sites alluding to writing their own VBA merge modules. Again this suggests that the basic print merge is not in the base API.

Comment: @shruti1810 Please stop these tag-edits. Your edits are being discussed on meta [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295565/do-we-need-a-coreldraw-vba-tag) and [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295302/is-this-implication-true-excel-vba-excel-vba).

Comment: So, you want to have VBA create a print merge, or run a print merge you have created/loaded?  Do you want to merge to printer, or merge to new document?  Is it ok if the print dialog, and or the pick new document, pops up?

Comment: @Yakk I would have settled for any of the above at the time, as it would have pointed me at the API / object model. I ended up writing the process myself.